# How to write poll data to a text file?

Tags: php

Im trying to make a poll in php. Im trying to gather data by writing the info to a txt file. How do I get the code to write the data to a txt file?

1. This all the code I have in my handler, how do I make it write to my txt file. Most of the stuff at the bottom doesn't matter yet. Try to look at the code that say if ($submit == 'submit') and what follows that.

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <title>Poll</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
       //no need for sport validation is unimportant and doesnt work
       if (isset($_REQUEST['Soda'])) {
           $Soda = $_REQUEST['Soda'];
       } else {
           $Soda = NULL;
           echo '<p class="error">You forgot to select your favorite soda!</p>';
       }
       //This is end of soda validation
       if (!empty($_REQUEST['Book'])) {
           $Book = $_REQUEST['Book'];
       } else {
           $Book = NULL;
           echo '<p class="error">You forgot to write in your favorite book!</p>';
       }
       //End of book validation
       if (isset($_REQUEST['SOTU'])) {
           $SOTU = $_REQUEST['SOTU'];
       } else { 
           $SOTU = NULL;
           echo '<p class="error">You forgot to select the two biggest issues of the                 state of the union address!</p>';
       }
       //End of SOTU validation
       if (isset($_REQUEST['Soda']) && !empty($_REQUEST['Book']) &&                               isset($_REQUEST['SOTU'])) {
           echo' Thank You for filling out the survey!<br> You can see the results of the pole' . "<a href=\"poll_results.php\"> here</a>!<br><br> Your response has been recorded.";
       } else {
           echo '<p class="error">Please go ' . "<a href=\"poll_form.html\">back</a>" . ' and fill out the poll!<p>';
       }
       //End of link responses
       //Define variables and make sure file works
       $submit = $_REQUEST['submit'];
       $filename = 'poll_data.txt';
       $handle = fopen($filename, 'a');
       //next is the stuff that is to be appended
           if ($submit == 'Submit') {
               fopen($filename, 'w');
               $newdata = $Soda . PHP_EOL;
               fwrite($handle, $newdata);
           } else { echo 'You didn\'t click submit';}
       //Now to sort the data and present it
       /*explode('PHP.EOL', $filename);
       $CC = 0;
       $P = 0;
       $MD = 0;
       $SS = 0;
       $BR = 0;
       $DLS = 0;
       $O = 0;
       foreach($filename as $value) {
           if ($value = 'Coca-Cola') {
               $CC = $CC + 1;
           }
           elseif ($value = 'Pepsi') {
               $P = $P + 1;
           }
           elseif ($value = 'MtnDew') {
               $MD = $MD + 1;
           }
           elseif ($value ='Sprite/Sierra-Mist') {
               $SS = $SS + 1;
           }
           elseif ('BigRed') {
               $BR = $BR + 1;
           }
           elseif ('DontLikeSoda') {
               $DLS = $DLS + 1;
           }
           elseif ('Other') {
               $O = $O + 1;
           }
       }*/
   ?>
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
   <title>Poll</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
    //no need for sport validation is unimportant and doesnt work
    if (isset($_REQUEST['Soda'])) {
        $Soda = $_REQUEST['Soda'];
    } else {
        $Soda = NULL;
        echo '<p class="error">You forgot to select your favorite soda!</p>';
    }
    //This is end of soda validation
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['Book'])) {
        $Book = $_REQUEST['Book'];
    } else {
        $Book = NULL;
        echo '<p class="error">You forgot to write in your favorite book!</p>';
    }
    //End of book validation
    if (isset($_REQUEST['SOTU'])) {
        $SOTU = $_REQUEST['SOTU'];
    } else { 
        $SOTU = NULL;
        echo '<p class="error">You forgot to select the two biggest issues of the                 state of the union address!</p>';
    }
    //End of SOTU validation
    if (isset($_REQUEST['Soda']) && !empty($_REQUEST['Book']) &&                               isset($_REQUEST['SOTU'])) {
        echo' Thank You for filling out the survey!<br> You can see the results of the pole' . "<a href=\"poll_results.php\"> here</a>!<br><br> Your response has been recorded.";
    } else {
        echo '<p class="error">Please go ' . "<a href=\"poll_form.html\">back</a>" . ' and fill out the poll!<p>';
    }
    //End of link responses
    //Define variables and make sure file works
    $submit = $_REQUEST['submit'];
    $filename = 'poll_data.txt';
    //next is the stuff that is to be appended
        if ($submit == 'Submit') {
            $handle = fopen($filename, 'a');
            fputs($handle, $Soda.PHP_EOL);
            fclose($handle);
        } else { echo 'You didn\'t click submit';}
    //Now to sort the data and present it
    /*explode('PHP.EOL', $filename);
    $CC = 0;
    $P = 0;
    $MD = 0;
    $SS = 0;
    $BR = 0;
    $DLS = 0;
    $O = 0;
    foreach($filename as $value) {
        if ($value = 'Coca-Cola') {
            $CC = $CC + 1;
        }
        elseif ($value = 'Pepsi') {
            $P = $P + 1;
        }
        elseif ($value = 'MtnDew') {
            $MD = $MD + 1;
        }
        elseif ($value ='Sprite/Sierra-Mist') {
            $SS = $SS + 1;
        }
        elseif ('BigRed') {
            $BR = $BR + 1;
        }
        elseif ('DontLikeSoda') {
            $DLS = $DLS + 1;
        }
        elseif ('Other') {
            $O = $O + 1;
        }
    }*/
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use

```
fopen($filename, 'r');
```

that should work.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: Thanks turned out it was fopen permissions that was tripping me up. The server I was runniing wouldnt allow me to use fopen. Found a way around it. Works now.